# Dask bag map: assign attribute to object

Tags: object, attributes, dask

I have a set of python objects (I am giving only one case: x in the code) that I want to process using dask bag. The resulting value of the computation will be assigned as attribute (x.test in the code bellow) to the objects.

```
import dask.bag as db

class Test():
    pass

x = Test()

def dask_test(x):
    somevalue = someprocess(x)
    setattr(x, "test", somevalue)

b = db.from_sequence([x], npartitions = 1)
b.map(dask_test).compute()
x.test
```

The above gives an error: AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute 'test'

The bellow here works fine.

```
setattr(x, "test", 'somevalue')
x.test
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're attempting to accomplish?

Comment: @joebeeson I am attempting to use dask bag multiprocessing to process some objects and assign resulting processing as an attribute to the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return a value from the `dask_test` function:

```py
def dask_test(x):
    setattr(x, "test", True)
    return x
```

[image]

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where and why is the attribute getting lost?

Comment: So, couple things. Dask is going to do a bit of serialization and copying under the covers and relying on mutations is a big ole' foot cannon you want to steer clear of. If you have a more concrete example of why specifically you're trying to do it *this* way, let me know. As it stands now your example is hard to correlate to a solution.